# How to pass a SimpleExoPlayer instance between two activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, exoplayer2.x

I am creating a music player like Spotify and was trying to achieve the functionality where the song continues getting played just above the `BottomNavigationBar` while navigating through the app and even when the activity/fragment which has the controls, album art and all is closed. So, when I tried to pass the instance of **SimpleExoPlayer** from the activity which initialized the player to the fragment in the home activity of my app through *Intent* like

```
...

override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra(RETURN_BACK_TO_LIBRARY_FRAG, TransferablePlayer(player as SimpleExoPlayer))
        setResult(101, intent)
        finish()
    }

...
```

**TransferablePlayer is a Parcelable**

```
...

@Parcelize
data class TransferablePlayer(val player: @RawValue SimpleExoPlayer): Parcelable

...
```

then I got the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer@91a2309

which simply means that **SimpleExoPlayer** class is not a `Serializable` and hence can not be passed through *Intent*.
Is there any way to move the same instance of *SimpleExoPlayer* around activities or is there any better approach to achieve the same results?

Comment: you can't. Just instantiate it in the 2nd activity

Comment: you should not try to pass anything except simple variables between Activities. Use service to shage a single player between 2 activities, for example

Comment: Or, perhaps all of this should be a single activity, using fragments for the distinct bits of UI.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for suggesting to use fragments but in my scenario, the problem got solved by making a singleton.